# Unable to set the image property of a NSImageView in swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsimageview

I'm trying to set a image to an NSImageView but unable to do it.
Here is my code

```
class zoomableImageView: NSImageView {
var newZoomFactor : CGFloat = 0 
// some function ...
}
```

in the appDelegate class

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: zoomableImageView!
   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    self.imageView.image = NSImage(named: "Carte.jpg")!
```

Here is my debug

```
(lldb) po self.imageView
<imageZoom.zoomableImageView: 0x600000180750>
```

the imageView is initialized

```
(lldb) po NSImage(named: "Carte.jpg")
▿ Optional(<NSImage 0x600000065b80 Name=Carte Size={376.74418604651163, 282.49833887043189} Reps=("NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000000a6600 Size={376.74418604651163, 282.49833887043189} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=1575x1181 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000162400")>)
```

the NSImage is created

but

```
(lldb) po self.imageView.image
nil
```

The assign is not working

Does some one have any idea ?
Tks for looking
Guillaume

Comment: not directly but the po self.imageView give a positive result, is it possible that imageView is not initialised ?

Answer (score 3):

Objects from a NIB file have to wait until awakeFromNib before they are loaded:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.imageView.image = NSImage(named: "Carte.jpg")!
}
```